Why is buffer output signal reduced to half?
I am designing a buffer and would like to deliver the full input signal to a 50 ohm load. For context, I am planning to use this buffer for a hartley oscillator. I am experiencing attenuation in my simulations though. The idea of the parallel capacitor on an inductor on the collector came from a previous post. How can I get the full 1V across the load? Below is the circuit:

Here is the output signal:


Try sweeping through different frequencies and observe the behavior.

Half -- in relation to what? What is VCC? What BJT type? Could you explain the choice of component values shown, if any?

Its supposed to be a buffer. Input should equal the output. input=1v ac signal.

Says who? Where did you find this circuit? Post a reference. It's also drawn poorly.

@xcaliber99 50 Ohm output Hartley is often developed by using an appropriate transformer. A lot of what makes it work is construction techniques and several taps on the inductor so that bandspread and bandset can be also adjusted. We don't see the larger context. And since everything matters I feel a bit blinded.

Reduce a "little" your "maximum time step" ...

Perhaps you should direct your questions along more general RF topics: what does it mean to "buffer" a signal?: Isolation. Then how do we get isolation at RF? How do we design an amplifier for given impedance?  How do we do impedance matching? How do we design or select transformers at these frequencies, or matching networks? (Mind that several of these, on a general level, span years of college curriculum, so don't expect short, easily understood answers, but applied study over a long period of time.)

Try this as a buffer:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This will be a buffer that can drive low impedance loads over a wide frequency range. There is much improvement that can be made to this circuit. But that really depends on "how good" do you need it to perform. You provided no additional requirements (distortion, power requirements, ambient temperature, input impedance, application, ect.) that govern the development of this circuit further.

Doesn't the diodes need to be the same voltage drop as Vbe if we are going to use this buffer?

@xcaliber99 That depends on how good you need the circuit to be :)  If they are isothermic with the transistors, they will be pretty damn close. Like I said, this is the first pass for a discrete transistor buffer. We could do much better with additional compensation and complexity.  Again, you presented no hard requirements pertaining to circuit performance. This might not even be the right approach with out knowing the application.

I 'm afraid to say i don't know enough to set a well-defined set of criteria. This is mostly for learning purposes. Like I said, the ultimate goal is to connect it to a hartly oscillator and then measure the signal. The input of the oscilloscope or spectrum measurement instrument needs to be 50 ohms though. For that purpose, I'm guessing I don't really need a very good buffer but I want a buffer that will maintain the oscilaltor signal. So the swing is 1v. At the output, i want the buffer to produce 1v. I don't know if this makes sense or if it is good. Taking things one step at a time.

@xcaliber99 If you're really picky about it, you can use the base-emitter junctions of two additional transistors, identical to the amplifying ones.

@Hearth Do you mean to connect it in the diode connected form?

@xcaliber99 For learning, this will certainly be enough; much more theory would be needed and understood to advance this circuit further. A few points: you don't need to drive 50 ohms when using an oscilloscope (unless your dealing with very high frequencies). So set the scope for "high-Z" inputs. Or remove your 50 ohm terminator. Also, if you do need a buffer for what you are doing, Just use a unity-gain stable Op-Amp configured as a buffer with at least enough BW for your oscillator. Mind the CM range and input/output I and V limits.

@xcaliber99 I updated the schematic to reflect the Bob Pease trick that I believe Hearth is talking about.

@xcaliber99 You could do that, or just leave the collectors floating; both will accomplish approximately the same thing for this circuit.

@MOSFET are there any sources you would like to suggest to further this circuit? I would like to work in RF range. Like 400-500 MHz maybe more. I am somewhat familiar with lower frequencies but RF is new and i want to learn how to handle problems that arise in RF.

The circuit you posted is not a buffer.  It is an amplifier, with gain that is very dependent on the frequency of the signal.  For a unity-gain buffer, consider an emitter follower.
Please add connection dots to your schematic.
Update:
Here is a common high speed buffer circuit approach, sometimes called a Complimentary-Symmetry Emitter Follower (CSEF).  This is the schematic for a specific buffer IC, but the circuit has been around in discrete form for decades.  National Semiconductor, Burr-Brown, Elantec, and others also have (or had) buffer chips based on the same circuit.

Source:  https://www.eeweb.com/high-speed-buffer-amplifier/

An emitter follower likely wouldn't be very effective at this frequency; take note of the time axis scale.

I don't see why not, it's only 6.6 MHz.  Very common in video processing circuits by Ampex and RCA, as was a source follower at the output of a camera tube such as a plumbicon.  I updated my answer with a more "robust" form.

One cycle in ~2.1ns is 6.6MHz???

OK, My Bad.  Way too high cognitive load, travel lag, sleep dep.  Never mind.  Still, the CSEF is a good performer.
